# V2: Sleep until webpage updates via ajax?

Tags: autohotkey

### My setup and why V2:

I have a simple macro that utilizes mousemove/click. I am using V2 because I hope it will be more reliable than V1 for this; however, in V1 I don't know if it's AHK's fault because the pixel locations of things on the screen seem to change irrespective of the script (for example, the location of an extension seems to shift by 10 px every day despite no DPI changes)....

### Goal:

I want to drag the mouse over some text to select it and copy it to the clipboard, but sometimes it takes more than 6 seconds for the text to appear;

other times, the text appears immediately! So, a lot of time can be saved by causing the script to act only immediately after the page updates.

### I'm currently just using sleeps:

```
#SingleInstance Force
^`::
{
Keywait "Control"
Send "{home}+{click 1855, 509}"
sleep 3000 ;;; This is where the page updates via ajax.
MouseClickDrag "left", 1705, 367, 1710, 402
sleep 1000
MouseClickDrag "left", 1660, 569, 451, 504
sleep 1000
Send "{ctrl down}c{ctrl up}{f1}"
return
}
```

## Desired changes:

By some means, I hope to figure out when the source has been updated, or when the div called `class="cite-header"` manifests, or when the pixels change, or anything like this... somehow I hope to tell the script that the page is updated.

### Long-term goal:

Eventually, I hope to click the button by targeting and grab the info directly by targeting the div that contains the info, but I think this will involve a lot of complex code so I am trying to just use a macro, now.

Comment: You don't seem to be setting [`CoordMode`](https://www.autohotkey.com/docs/v2/lib/CoordMode.htm), which could cause this this "shift in pixels values" you're referring to. Also, if you really think AHK is the tool for this job (hard to say, since don't know what you're actually doing here), [Chrome.ahk](https://www.autohotkey.com/boards/viewtopic.php?f=6&t=42890) could be what you're looking for.

Comment: @0x464e Unfortunately, there is no coordmode that fixes this issue because the px location changes in Screen, Window, and Client. I am going to try Chrome.ahk and hopefully post some beginner script & tutorial here. Thank you.

Comment: @0x464e There might still be some bugs with chrome.ahk because I downloaded the library and the dependency libraries (json), and when I try to run the examples it says "call to nonexistent function" in the JSONX file.

Comment: Works just fine for me. Maybe try to just download from the Github [releases page](https://github.com/G33kDude/Chrome.ahk/releases) to be sure you didn't mess something up with the dependencies. Or did you maybe try with AHK v2? Chrome.ahk is unfortunately still v1. Although it seems its codebase is so small that it should only take a few moments to convert it to v2.